# Working with EventListener in Firebase for Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Consider, I store the following Key-Value pair in Firebase Database.

> Key: "CarBrand" and Value: "Audi"

I read the **Value** for this **Key** from Firebase Database and display the Value in TextView. For this, I use an EventListener.

The problem I face with an EventListsner is since it runs on a separate thread, the TextView returns a **NullPointerException** even before the Value is fetched from Firebase.

To overcome the issue I have been using this dirty trick (using a Handler with 500 to 1000 ms delay). Can someone guide me the right way to fetch and display the **Value** in *TextView* or *any other Views*

PS: Apologies for this codeless Question

Thanks

**EDIT**: More the Code, better the question. The sample code is as follows

```
String CardBrand;

private ValueEventListener contentListener() {
    contentListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Pull Values for all available Keys
            CarBrand = dataSnapshot.child("CarBrand").getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    return contentListener;
}

dbContent.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(contentListener());
mTextView.setText(CarBrand);
```

The above code results in error. To avoid this, I replaced the last line of code with

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mTextView.setText(CarBrand);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

So this is what I have been doing. What would be the right way to display the Text in TextView in my Case?

Comment: Please share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong as the listener is updating the `String CarBrand` But since the code is not in sync and casing the Error. You need to update the code

```
private ValueEventListener contentListener() {
    contentListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Pull Values for all available Keys
            String CarBrand = 
dataSnapshot.child("CarBrand").getValue(String.class);
            updateBrand(CarBrand);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    return contentListener;
}

dbContent.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(contentListener());
```

**you need to create a Function to update the value**

```
/* updates the Car brand Text
   TODO:: You can do anystuff you want to do after anything gets 
   updated
*/
public void updateBrand(String brand){
     mTextView.setText(CarBrand);
}
```

**NOTE** : Put Listener on the Data you are actually looking for changes.

Comment: But what if, instead of a Car Name I have a Url of a file that needs to be downloaded. I am using this library (github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/…) to download files from URL. Does this mean I need to post all the Code inside the onDataChange()?

Comment: You can use a Model to which you can assign the values you need .
    Car myCar = 
    dataSnapshot.child("carID").getValue(String.class);
                updateMyCar(Car);

where updateMyCar will do whatever you need to do with the Model as class Car will have (name, brand , image_url,model_id,etc..)

Comment: I understand the Model concept. I will try the code in URL mentioned above, inside onDataChange() and get back to you

Comment: Okay Sure. also if possible do share the database structure.

Comment: Thank you. Working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with the result of some callback (like ValueEventListener) you should execute your code inside the overriding methods.

```
String cardBrand;

private ValueEventListener contentListener() {
    contentListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Pull Values for all available Keys
            carBrand = dataSnapshot.child("CarBrand").getValue(String.class);
            mTextView.setText(carBrand);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    return contentListener;
}

dbContent.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(contentListener());
```

Comment: But what if, instead of a Car Name I have a Url of a file that needs to be downloaded. I am using this library (https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking#downloading-a-file-from-server) to download files from URL. Does this mean I need to post all the Code inside the onDataChange()?

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you small example:

This class responsible for retreiving the link for you, and it doesn't know what will you do with it, so it takes Callback and pass the result to your callback, where you can do anything you want.
public class SomeDataSource {

```
void getData(Callback callback) {
    String url = Backend.GetUrl(); 
    callback.onDownloadUrlReceived(url);
}
```

}

this is description of callback. Which you can implement to handle data from SomeDataSource

```
public interface Callback {
    void onDownloadUrlReceived(String url)
}
```

usage

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SomeDataSource downloader = new SomeDataSource();
    //here callback is implemented, and you can handle data from SomeDataSource like you want.
    downloader.getData(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadUrlReceived(String url) {
            do wat you want with url
        }
    });
}
```